# How to read = separated data from file

Tags: c++

I have a data file that contains key value pairs separated by an = character.

Example data file is like below.

```
A = 1 
B = 2
C = 3 
D = 4
```

I want to read only some keys from the data file. For example, I only want to read A and C keys in this example. I used a for loop and getline to do this but unable to get data.

Below is the MWE.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// pretend file stream
std::istringstream data(R"(
A = 0.0000
B = 1.0000
C = 2.0000
D = 3.0000
)");

int main()
{

    double A, C;
    
    for(std::string key; std::getline(data, key, '='); ){
        std::cout << key << "Printed Key." << std::endl;
        if(key == "A "){
            data >> A;
            std::cout << A << std::endl;
        }
        else if(key == "C "){
            data >> C;
            std::cout << C << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

For some reason when I print the key, Its giving the following output. Instead of reading from where it left off.

```
A Printed Key.
 0.0000
B Printed Key.
 1.0000
C Printed Key.
 2.0000
D Printed Key.
 3.0000
Printed Key.
```

Comment: "unable to get data" is not a problem description. What exactly happens when you run this code, with what exact input? Why is that wrong, and what should happen instead?

Comment: As I have explained in the description, I need to read only specific keys in the data file with several other key-value pairs.

Comment: What else you could: `std::string key, sep; double value; if ((data >> key >> sep >> value) && (sep == '=')) { /* do what you want to do with the input */ }`. I must admit that this is a quite simple solution relying on the fact that `=` is surrounded by spaces but your approach seems to rely on this as well.

Comment: tell us what you observe not only your interpretation. "I cannot do it" is what you concluded, but why? What does the code do? How does that differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: This is one of the cases where print-based debugging is very confusing. Luckily, this is a small program, so **step through it in the debugger**. Observe the value of `key` in each iteration. Does `key` ever contain the exact strings `"A "` or `"C "`? Now figure out what causes it (it's the `getline` call)

Comment: It contains for the first key. For the rest of them its actually including everything after the = to the next =., even though I am reading the value inside the if condition.

Comment: No, it does not. It contains `"\nA "` because the raw literal includes newlines. If you tell `getline` to read until it sees a `=`, it will do just that. It will not consider actual newline characters to be special.

Comment: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81aaa1af04477354)

Comment: @Scheff. In this case yes. But I am actually trying to read from a file. There it works for the first key.

Comment: There is no difference concerning formatted stream input whether you read from a file or a string - assuming the format is fix and exactly like exposed. Mixing formatted input and `getline()` needs extra care. Btw. consider that you don't consume the value if you skip the key in your code. (Not to mention that you replaced the delimiter in `getline()` what's your other issue...)

Comment: Try to modify your code  if(key == "\nA ") ... else if(key == " 1.0000\nC ") ... then those checks will match.

Comment: If you surround your key output with visible delimiters, you will see that the first value is `"\n A "`, the second is `" 0.0000 \nB "`, the third is `" 1.0000\nC "`,... (Verifying that the input is what you expect instead of assuming is often a good first step.) The reason that it works for the first entry when you're reading a file is that the file does not start with a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the second `getline()`, the `key` value will be what is left in the line of the previous called until the next `=` in the following line.
This example will make it easier to understand.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// pretend file stream
std::istringstream data("A = 0.0000\n"
                        "B = 1.0000\n"
                        "C = 2.0000\n"
                        "D = 3.0000\n");

int main()
{

    double A, C;
    
    for(std::string key; std::getline(data, key, '='); ){
        std::cout << key << "Printed Key." << std::endl;
        if(key == "A "){
            data >> A;
            std::cout << A << " A value printed" << std::endl;
        }
        else if(key == " 1.0000\nC "){
            data >> C;
            std::cout << C << " C value printed" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

You can add another `getline()` at the end of each loop to get the rest of the line and the code will work

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// pretend file stream
std::istringstream data("A = 0.0000\n"
                        "B = 1.0000\n"
                        "C = 2.0000\n"
                        "D = 3.0000\n");

int main()
{

    double A, C;
    
    for(std::string key; std::getline(data, key, '='); ){
        std::cout << key << "Printed Key." << std::endl;
        if(key == "A "){
            data >> A;
            std::cout << A << " A value printed" << std::endl;
        }
        else if(key == "C "){
            data >> C;
            std::cout << C << " C value printed" << std::endl;
        }
        std::getline(data, key);
    }

}
```

Comment: While this works, it is nicer to use the input's structure to your advantage. The canonical approach here would call `getline` once to read a line at a time, then use an `istringstream` to do dissect the line.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `ini` file or part of it. So instead reinventing the wheel it is better to use ready solution like boost.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::property_tree;
    ptree values;
    ini_parser::read_ini(std::cin, values);
    std::cout << values.get<double>("A") << '\n';
    std::cout << values.get<double>("B") << '\n';
    std::cout << values.get<double>("C") << '\n';
    std::cout << values.get<double>("D") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7s9d57